# ASP.NET Core UI for managing Identity users and roles

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

In a .net 5 MVC project that uses Identity for authentication, is there a built in option to manage the roles (crud) and user <> role relationships (add and removed roles to a user)?

I have found some tutorials that could work:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/adding-role-authorization-to-a-asp-net-mvc-core-application/
https://www.yogihosting.com/aspnet-core-identity-roles/

But before I go recreating the wheel, I just wanted to be sure there isn't some functionality contained within the framework that I am missing.

Edit: Just to clarify, my question is regarding giving user roles e.g. Admin, manager, staff.
I've always used identity and always had to create my own logic for creating and assigning roles to users. But keep thinking there must be a standard way to do this.

Comment: To not recreate the wheel, use an external identity provider. i.e. MS login or Google login or FB login. Assuming this is an internet "connected" application

Comment: I've never used either, how do they handle roles?

Comment: You still need to handle roles because that is specific to your app. But the identity provider handles all of the identity stuff - logging in, changing password, password strength etc. Nowadays I'll rarely use any service that requires me to think up a new login and password.

Answer (score 2):

A few options. One is just the admin UI and the other is a web framework with admin UI

https://github.com/mguinness/IdentityManagerUI

https://docs.aspnetzero.com/en/aspnet-core-angular/latest/Features-Angular-Role-Management

Answer (score 0):

for different roles in multiple groups

https://github.com/rogwool/two

- Might have been better with a GroupId key in AspNetUserRoles

Answer (score 0):

This https://github.com/iammukeshm/CustomUserManagement.MVC may be of benefit in developing your own UI, something which I'm trying to do myself.